# Sendusingaccount only works when Outlook is not running

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to automate certain calendar invites in Outlook. The automation is based on VBA in Excel.

I need to send the invites from a secondary Outlook (Exchange) account that I have full access to. The below code is a simple test, that should do just that. But for some reason it only works, when Outlook is not already running.

When I run the code **while Outlook is already running**, the invite is created, but the "from" field is empty and the invite only shows up in the recipient's calendar, not in my own calendar.

**When Outlook is *not* running** when the code is executed, everything works: the invite is created, the "from" field correctly shows "mysecondaryaccount@domain.com" and the invite shows in both the receiver's calendar and in my own calendar.

When i try to put in my primary account in the code (i.e. Set olAcct = OL.Session.Accounts("myprimaryaccount@domain.com")), everything runs perfectly no matter the state of Outlook (i.e. running or not running).

Any ideas on how to fix this, so the code can run with Outlook already running?

```
Sub test()
Dim OL As Outlook.Application, olApp As Outlook.AppointmentItem, olAcct As Outlook.Account
Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olApp = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set olAcct = OL.Session.Accounts("mysecondaryaccount@domain.com")
olApp.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
olApp.RequiredAttendees = "whoyiamsendingto@domain.com"
olApp.Subject = "test"
olApp.body = "testing"
olApp.SendUsingAccount = olAcct
olApp.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: The Outlook object needs to be initiated differently depending on whether there is already an instance of Outlook running (regardless of whether it's visible.)  [This](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm) will test whether it's open. I can't remember the syntax off the top of my head for grabbing an existing vs. new instance of Outlook with an object, but it's only a Google away. I beleive it's `CreateObject` versus `GetObject`.

Comment: Thank you, ashleedawg.

I have tried both getting and creating object to no avail. The same problem occurs: the "from" is empty.

The weird thing is, that I can have the sub loop through all my Outlook accounts (there are two) and have it display both of them. I can also set the account to my primary account (Set olAcct = OL.Session.Accounts("myprimaryaccount@domain.com"), which works fine and populates the "from" field.